# MIPS swap function

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

As is obvious from my question history today, I am working on a MIPS project that will reverse a string, in this case "Hello, World". I think I have my loop and string reversal functions correct, but I cannot figure out the swap function itself, or how to output the manipulated string.

I know that the basic swap for something like this would be:

```
sll $t1, $a1, 2
add $t1, $a0,$t1
lb $t0,0($t1)
lb $t2, 4($t1)

sb $t0,0($t1)
sb $t2, 4($t1)
jr $ra
```

But I have no idea what that does or how I interpret that to fit my code. If some holy saint out there could explain how that works and how syscalls work I would be eternally grateful. My code below:

```
.data 

    string: .asciiz "Hello, World!"

.text
main:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, string #store string in a0
    syscall



    jal stringreverse

stringreverse:
    add $t0,$a0,$zero   #base address of string
    add $a1, $zero,14   #stores size of string in a1
    addi $t2, $a1, -1   #j = length -1
    add $t3,$zero,$zero     #i = 0

loop:
    jal swap
    addi $t2,$t2,-1     #j--
    addi $t3,$t3,+1     #i++

    slt  $t7,$t3,$t2 #set t7 to 1 when j is less than i
    bne  $t7,$zero,loop # if i is greater than j, keep looping
    j done
swap:   #swaps the sooner element with the later and returns back to the loop
    lb      $v0,0($t3)              # updated to fit my registers t3 =i
    lb      $v1,0($t2)              # updated to fit my registers t2 =j

    sb      $v1,0($t3)              
    sb      $v0,0($t2)              

    jr $ra

done:
    .....procedure here.....
    syscall
```

Comment: See my answer to your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49393986/mips-char-array-reversal-translation-from-c/49396380#49396380 BTW, you should really just edit the original rather than posting a [slightly modified] duplicate

Comment: The reverse is similar in structure to mine. In my reverse/swap, I use `char*` _pointers_ throughout (vs. index variables). Notice that `main -> reverse -> swap`, so the `$ra` value from `main` needs to be preserved by `reverse` because the `jal swap` clobbers it

Comment: Also, notice that from the mips ABI, only `$s0-$s7` must be preserved (and the stack register must, at function exit, point to the same place it was a function entry). Otherwise, any reg can be used for any purpose. I deliberately through in the curveball of using `$v0/$v1` in my `swap` (vs. `$t*`). The only truly hardwired [by the architecture] regs are `$ra` and `$zero`

Comment: I appreciate the advice, I didn't know the etiquette. As for your second comment, can you elaborate? I am working off of examples and do not have much knowledge as to the actual workings of the procedures. So im not really sure what you mean about the $ra value.

Comment: When you do `jal func`, it puts the return address (the address _after_ the `jal` into the `$ra` (return address) register) and then jumps to `func`. The use of `$ra` by `jal` is one of the few hardwired choices. The usual way to return is `jr $ra` which is jump to address in `$ra`. This is the normal sequence, but `jr` is _not_ tied to `$ra`, you can use any other reg (e.g. in my code, I used `$t0` to illustrate this: `jr $t0` because I saved `$ra` into `$t0` earlier)

Comment: Okay so that was just a heads up. I gotcha! I just ran the code, the edited version with your swap argument that I show above, and I am getting a runtime error, probably due to messing up on translating your registers to mine.

Comment: line 31: Runtime exception at 0x0040003c: address out of range 0x00000000     Its the first line of my swap, so i just assume my i value, or LHS, is off. Any ideas? Something obvious? Also, thanks for holding my hand

Comment: Your `$t2/$t3` are indexes not pointers, so the `lb` will fault (e.g. `$t3` has zero in it at start). `lb $v0,0($t3)` is like `char v0 = *t3`. `lb $v0,5($t3)` would be like `char v0 = *(t3 + 5)`. So, your reverse is doing [in C]: `swap(i,j)` instead of `swap(&array[i],&array[j])` I've updated my answer on your other page to help

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're treating the lb (load byte instruction) like a la (load address instruction).

You probably want to do something more like this:

```
swap:
    lb    $temp1,   str($t2)    #load temp1 address with byte at $t2 in str 
    lb    $temp2,   str($t1)    #load temp2 address with byte at $t1 in str
    sb    $temp2,   str($t2)    #store temp2 byte into $t2'th position in str
    sb    $temp1,   str($t1)    #store temp1 byte into $t1'th position in str
    jr    $ra
```

with some data like:

```
.data
str:
    .asciiz "your string here"
```

Hopefully this clears things up a bit for you.

Comment: I believe that the $a#  and $v# registers are typically reserved to be used as arguments for system calls. In this case the relevant system calls you're looking for are 
`li      $v0,    4       #system call to print
 la      $a0,    ($regwithstringaddress)   #load string
 syscall`       

and 

`li      $v0,    10      #system call to exit
 syscall                 `

Comment: Huge shoutout my man! So my first li that I begin the main with has been wrong all along? I should be at                                                    
        li $v0, 8
 la $a0, string 
 syscall     in order to read in the string?

Comment: Yes, the code in my previous comment should load $a0 with the string and then print it out.

Comment: Note that `str($reg)` is only possible if you set up your simulator to have static data in the low 32kiB of address space, e.g. data section starting at address `0` or `0x1000` or something.  Otherwise a label address can't fit in a 16-bit signed immediate for a single I-type instruction like `lb` or `lw`.